# Grails applications with CAS enabled

Tags: authentication, grails, authorization, cas

Fellow grails developers, help me to find out the most groovy way to accomplish following.
So, I have a Tomcat with enabled CAS, which is used by all webapps hosted. 
One of these webapps is grails application.

As for files in web-app folder of this grails application, they just can see request.getRemoteUser() as expected.

As for the grails-app (to get user name in controllers, for example), as far as I can understand, I should take some additional steps.

My question is - what is the most groovy way to accomplish this?
Off the top of my head, just trying to resolve this issue by any means, I can forward requests to controllers from web-app part, but it quiet perversive. Or I can install grails CAS plugin, but that means I'm just doubling configs, since I already head configure web.xml.

Or I can (can I?) use somehow for these purposes springSecurityService?

But what is the most elegant way to get user name in grails application when, as for web applications, there is already working CAS?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few different ways to handle this:

1. Use spring-security-core with spring-security-cas; but like you say, this adds a second CAS layer
2. Access user information through request.remoteUser, as in any other webapp
3. configure a [PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.html) and a [RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.html) to get spring-security to trust the request headers set up tomcat; there's some information on setting this up at http://dickersonshypotheticalblog.blogspot.com/2011/05/grails-spring-security-using.html

Comment: well, the thing is I can not see request.remoteUser in grails controllers at all, that is why I came up with this question.